# Can I say (have go this through)?

Tags: conditional-constructions, phrasal-verbs

I saw this sentence from my friend's WhatsApp story. He's an English learner like me. This is the sentence by the way:

> Had I not been a jerk I would not have been going this through.

I think, there's something I don't understand about the sentence. I've looked up the phrasal verb **go through** and it seems that this phrasal verb is not reversible (I'm not sure if this is a correct way to say this).

I mean, usually if there's a noun that goes before the adverb particle, OALD would use the bi-implication symbol (⇔) to indicate that, but it doesn't have. Anyway, does that sentence above sound grammatical? If it isn't, could you please suggest the grammatical that would likely sond natural and grammatical?

Comment: Your friend made a mistake. It should be, "*... going **through this***".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the phrasal verb 'go through' cannot be reversed, but your friend has reversed it, thus making an error. He should have written:

> Had I not been a jerk I would not have been going through this.